# grpc make can't find protoc 3

Tags: macos, grpc

I installed grpc-java according to the [instructions](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java) on my Mac (running Mavericks). This included installing protobuf v3.0.0-alpha-2, which I did:

```
$ which protoc
/usr/local/bin/protoc

$ /usr/local/bin/protoc --version
libprotoc 3.0.0
```

The Java examples work fine. Now I'd like to try the C++ examples and, ideally, have a C++ client talk to a Java server and visa-versa.

I cloned grpc and attempted to install it. `sudo make install` and, subsequently, `make verify-install` fail, telling me that protobuf 3 is not installed:

```
$ make verify-install
We couldn't find protoc 3.0.0+ installed on your system. While this
won't prevent grpc from working, you won't be able to compile
and run any meaningful code with it.


Please download and install protobuf 3.0.0+ from:

   https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases

Once you've done so, or if you think this message is in error,
you can re-run this check by doing:

   make verify-install
```

On line 259 of grpc/Makefile, I see this test:

```
PROTOC_CHECK_CMD = protoc --version | grep -q libprotoc.3
```

If I run `protoc --version` on my Mac, I see something different (see above), so I tried changing the line above to

```
PROTOC_CHECK_CMD = protoc --version | grep -q 'libprotoc 3.0.0'
```

However I get the same error from `make verify-install`.

I'e also tried removing the PROTOBUF_CHECK_CMD and PROTOC_CHECK_CMD tests at run_dep_checks (about line #895) but install still fails with the same error.

When I run make on grpc-common/cpp/helloworld, it builds, but greeter_client and greeter_server both fail:

```
$ ./greeter_server
E0310 17:38:23.349841000 140735186797328 server.c:617] assertion failed: grpc_is_initialized() && "call grpc_init()"
Abort trap: 6
```

I assume because the problem with installing grpc.

So, protobuf 3 is clearly installed. How can I convince the Makefile of that, or at least bypass that test?

Comment: The message about protoc missing is not a build failure, it's just informational. Note that it says "this won't prevent grpc from working".

Comment: That original `grep` command should work. `grep` uses regular expressions, so `.` matches any character, and it does substring matching, so it should match the `libprotoc 3` part of the version string. In any case, that shouldn't be the problem. If it was, the Makefile in the C++ helloworld example would not have succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

The message you are seeing about protoc does not indicate that `make` failed. It is just a warning. You successfully installed gRPC and successfully built the hello world example.

The example does not work on Mac due to a bug in gRPC that is currently being investigated in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/1007).

Comment: Yes, I exchanged some emails on this with Nicolas Noble on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/grpc-io earlier today. I see there's a pull request to fix the Makefile problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `sudo make install` installed the protoc under `/usr/local/bin` but `grpc` looks under `/usr/bin`.
Try to configure protobuf using:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

This will install the protoc binary in a place that grpc is expecting it. When you do `sudo make install` on grpc then sudo will find protoc properly.
You can verify that sudo sees it with this command:

```
sudo which protoc
sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'
```

Note that `sudo echo $PATH` does not tell you where sudo's path is.