# Are the grpc examples intended to speak across languages?

Tags: java, go, grpc

Are the gRPC examples intended to interoperate? I can run the Java client-server examples entirely with Java. I can Go examples entirely with Go. But Go's hello world client won't talk with Java's hello world server.

In one terminal, from grpc-java:

```
$ ./gradlew :grpc-examples:helloWorldServer
:grpc-core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
...
:grpc-examples:helloWorldServer
Mar 10, 2015 7:01:50 PM io.grpc.examples.helloworld.HelloWorldServer start
INFO: Server started, listening on 50051
> Building 96% > :grpc-examples:helloWorldServer
```

In another terminal, from grpc-common/go

```
$ go run greeter_client/main.go
2015/03/10 19:02:47 could not greet: rpc error: code = 12 desc = "Method not found: /helloworld.Greeter/SayHello"
exit status 1
```

Not the cross-language example I was expecting. SayHello is there, but is the problem with path or case sensitivity? Am I missing something, or is this cross-language cooperation an intent not yet realized?

(Caveat--I don't know Go, and I've been [unable to build grpc for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28974708/1316011)).

Answer (score 4):

The two examples you are using are based on incompatible proto definitions. The problem is that the java example is using the package name `grpc.example.helloworld` and the go example is using just the `helloworld`.

And because the package name is part of the `URL` path (`/helloworld.Greeter/SayHello`) the call fails (the java server is expecting `/grpc.example.helloworld.Greeter/SayHello`).

You can see it in the generated code.

Java:

```
private GreeterServiceDescriptor() {
  sayHello = createMethodDescriptor(
      "grpc.example.helloworld.Greeter", METHOD_SAY_HELLO);
}
```

Go:

```
var _Greeter_serviceDesc = grpc.ServiceDesc{
        ServiceName: "helloworld.Greeter",
        HandlerType: (*GreeterServer)(nil),
        Methods: []grpc.MethodDesc{
            {
                MethodName: "SayHello",
                Handler: _Greeter_SayHello_Handler,
            },
        },
        Streams: []grpc.StreamDesc{},
}
```

Comment: So what's the solution? The examples claim to be build off the same [helloworld.proto](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-common/blob/master/protos/helloworld.proto). Were they? Shouldn't it build compatible URLs? (Sorry. I might understand this if I could get the *expletive* C++ stuff to build. I hadn't planned on having to learn Go when I tackled this.)

Comment: They are not, the java example is using this one: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/main/proto/hello_world.proto